# Get Element position from outer DIv

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get the element placed in inner div from outer div?
To clarify vague question, picture is provided below

[image: div]

In this picture.

Big Black Rectangle = Outer DIV , id = "outer-div"

Red rectangle = First inner DIV , id = "red-inner-div"

Blue rectangle = Second inner DIV , id = "blue-inner-div"

There is a textarea placed in red and blue div. Top and left is given in the picture

Suppose the ID of the textarea in Red Div is called "TA1", and blue one is called "TA2".

Is it possible to get the position of "TA1" or "TA2" from outer-div? For example, TA2 has top and left of 150 inside blue-inner-div , but I wanted to know what the TA2's top and left is from the view of outer-div, which is definitely not 150.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can probably get the page offset of your textarea and deduct the page offset of the parent element.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/position/ or http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: @andleer the OP never mentioned "jquery" here...

Comment: @gustavohenke, is there something wrong with jQuery?

Comment: We're at 2013, if he isn't using jQuery, there's no why to include a 80 kb minified lib to do such a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe...

```
var offset = { top: 0, left: 0 };
do {
  offset.top += elem.offsetTop;
  offset.left += elem.offsetLeft;

  elem = elem.parentNode;
} while (elem != null && elem.id !== "outer-div");
```

Take in account that if `elem` is not contained by `outer-div`, this will return its position within the document.

Another aproach, a little heavier but it's very close to jQuery's solution:

```
function getOffset(elem) {
  var offset = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  var docElem = document.documentElement;

  return {
    top: offset.top + window.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop,
    left: offset.left + window.pageXOffset - docElem.clientLeft
  };
}

var offsetOuter = getOffset(document.getElementById("outer-div"));
var offsetTextarea = getOffset(document.getElementById("TA1"));

console.log(offsetOuter.left - offsetTextarea.left); // ta-da
```

I've considered that you're using only vanilla JS, no libs (jQuery or whatever).

Comment: Yes, I am using vanilla JS and your solution worked very well, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

position from outer div...

```
$(function(){
    alert($("#TA1").offset().left-$("#outer-div").offset().left);
    alert($("#TA2").offset().left-$("#outer-div").offset().left);
});
```

for reference : http://jsfiddle.net/GF9VM/

P.S. same way you can get top.

Comment: I have to comment the same thing I commented in the question post: he never mentioned he's using jQuery.